# Difference between these two pointer methods

Tags: c, pointers

Decode1:

```
void decode1(int *xp, int *yp, int *zp){
 int x = *xp;
 int y = *yp; 
 int z = *zp;
 xp = &z;
 yp = &x;
 zp = &y;
}
```

Decode2:

```
 void decode2(int *xp, int *yp, int *zp){
 int x = *xp;
 int y = *yp; 
 int z = *zp;
 *xp = z;
 *yp = x;
 *zp = y;
}
```

Decode1 will change the pointer to address of the z, x, and y. Decode2 will instead change the value at the address of the pointer. Are these two methods interchangeable? Are there situations where one is more correct than the other?

Comment: Decode1 do nothing after return.

Comment: *Re-assigning a variable* (`xp = &z`) is not the same thing as *changing the data* (`*xp = z`) pointed to ..

Comment: Suppose you write down the address of your girlfriend on a piece of paper.

Method 1 corresponds to someone making a copy of that piece of paper (and immediately losing the copy).

Method 2 corresponds to someone going to the address on the piece of paper and reinstalling her desktop operating system.

They're not the same thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No they are not interchangeable and they don't do the same thing.

`decode1` will not work and `decode2` will work (assuming that you want to swap the variables).

The `decode1` function places `x`, `y` and `z` on the stack and these variables only *exist* while the function is executing. The moment it returns these variables no longer point to valid memory. Also, the pointers `xp`, `yp` and `zp` are copies of the pointers that were passed to the function so you won't be modifying the original pointers (hence altering them in the function does absolutely nothing).

The `decode2` function will work as expected.

Answer (score 4):

Decode2 is correct procedure. In Decode1, after end of the call stack, the address you have assigned in xp,yp,zp will be vanished.

Answer (score 2):

`decode1` attempts to returns pointers to local variables but in the end simply does nothing. Use `decode2`.